# redirigir luego de acreditar el pago

Tags: javascript, json, laravel-5

Estoy integrando pagos con tarjeta en mi web, hasta ahora el proceso esta correcto, pero necesito **redirigir a otra URL una vez  el status sea status: "rejected" o status: "aproved"**
(Aclaro Tengo poco conocimiento en javascript) y en la documentación que sigo no hay más datos.

El backend lo tengo resuelto, cuando un pago se hace correctamente recibo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora necesito redirigir a otro sitio por ejemplo /success

```
 <script>
       const cardForm = mp.cardForm({
  amount: "100.5",
  autoMount: true,
  form: {
    id: "form-checkout",
    cardholderName: {
      id: "form-checkout__cardholderName",
      placeholder: "Nombre",
    },
    cardholderEmail: {
      id: "form-checkout__cardholderEmail",
      placeholder: "E-mail",
    },
    cardNumber: {
      id: "form-checkout__cardNumber",
      placeholder: "Número de la tarjeta",
    },
    expirationDate: {
      id: "form-checkout__expirationDate",
      placeholder: "MM/YY",
    },
    securityCode: {
      id: "form-checkout__securityCode",
      placeholder: "000",
    },
    installments: {
      id: "form-checkout__installments",
      placeholder: "Cuotas",
    },
    identificationType: {
      id: "form-checkout__identificationType",
      placeholder: "Tipo de documento",
    },
    identificationNumber: {
      id: "form-checkout__identificationNumber",
      placeholder: "Número de documento",
    },
    issuer: {
      id: "form-checkout__issuer",
      placeholder: "Banco emisor",
    },
  },
  callbacks: {
    onFormMounted: error => {
      if (error) return console.warn("Form Mounted handling error: ", error);
      console.log("Form mounted");
    },
    onSubmit: event => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const {
        paymentMethodId: payment_method_id,
        issuerId: issuer_id,
        cardholderEmail: email,
        amount,
        token,
        installments,
        identificationNumber,
        identificationType,
      } = cardForm.getCardFormData();

      fetch("/process_payment", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          token,
          issuer_id,
          payment_method_id,
          transaction_amount: Number(amount),
          installments: Number(installments),
          description: "Descripción del producto",
          payer: {
            email,
            identification: {
              type: identificationType,
              number: identificationNumber,
            },
                        },
                    }),
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(result => {
                        if(!result.hasOwnProperty("error_message")) {
                            document.getElementById("success-response").style.display = "block";
                            document.getElementById("payment-id").innerText = result.id;
                            document.getElementById("payment-status").innerText = result.status;
                            document.getElementById("payment-detail").innerText = result.detail;
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById("error-message").textContent = result.error_message;
                            document.getElementById("fail-response").style.display = "block";
                        }
                        
                        $('.container__payment').fadeOut(500);
                        setTimeout(() => { $('.container__result').show(500).fadeIn(); }, 500);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        alert("Unexpected error\n"+JSON.stringify(error));
                    });
            },
    onFetching: (resource) => {
      console.log("Fetching resource: ", resource);

      // Animate progress bar
      const progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
      progressBar.removeAttribute("value");

      return () => {
        progressBar.setAttribute("value", "0");
      };
    }
  },
});
   </script>
```

Ahora solo tengo hecho que en la vista imprima el status y el ID, solo necesito redirigir a otra URL.

También me gustaría saber si es una buena práctica hacerlo de esta forma

Comment: `if (status === 'approved') window.location.href = 'misitio.com/success'`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, podria aplicarlo en mi codigo .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo digo que en la promesa dónde entra result es mas efectivo acceder al valor en el objeto directamente

```javascript
.then(result => {
if(result.status == "approved"){
//Tu lógica de aprobación
// window.location.href = "/thanks";
// Ejemplo de redirigir 
}else{
//Tu lógica de rechazo
}
})
```

Igual el backend puede regresar un booleano y solo usar

```javascript
if(result.status){}
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, si quisiera pasar los valores de 'status' dentro del if a la otra vista "/thanks"; con js como podria hacerlo?